# How to align two input boxes on same line but either ends

Tags: html, css, input, css-float

I'm having trouble aligning two input boxes on the same line. Whenever I float one to the right, it immediately pushes it to the next line.

How can I have two input boxes on the same line, one on the left and one aligned to the right, without it being pushed to the next line?

[JS Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5fv26bz9/3/)

```css
.inline {
  display: inline;
}

input {
  width: 15%;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
}

.body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 0 height: 100%;
  line-height: 200%;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}

.footer,
.push {
  line-height: 120%;
  height: 112px;
  /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="body">

    <div class="wrapper">

      <span class="inline">
         <input class="inputbold" type="text" name="" placeholder="boldinput"  /> 
         <div style="text-align: right;">
          <input class="inputbold" type="text"  name="" placeholder="blah"/>
         </div>
      </span>

    </div>

  </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: `display: inline;` on both, `float: left` on one, `float: right` on the other and some sensible widths set on both, `display: table` on the container and then `display: table-cell` on both, and plenty of other ways. You've got a mess there.

Comment: Typo in your last CSS selector `.footer, .push {`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because your second input field is wrapped inside of a  element. Removing it will fix your issue.

```
<div class="body">    
   <div class="wrapper">
     <span class="inline">
       <input class="inputbold" type="text" name="" placeholder="boldinput"  />     
       <input class="inputbold" type="text"  name="" placeholder="blah"/> </div>
     </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a lot of wrapping elements in there.

The simplest option woud seem to be just to float them left and right.

```css
input {
  width: 15%;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Arial;
  float: left;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
}
input:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="inputbold" type="text" name="" placeholder="boldinput" />
  <input class="inputbold" type="text" name="" placeholder="blah" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did:

```
<div class="body">

<div class="wrapper">
<span class="inline">

 <input class="inputbold" type="text" name="" placeholder="boldinput"  /> 
    <input class="inputbold" type="text"  name="" placeholder="blah"/>


  </div>

</span>

    </div>

    </div>
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5fv26bz9/5/)

Comment: @Jimmy And [here is an updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fv26bz9/5/) where the second textbox floats to the right

Answer (score 0):

you just have to add display:inline-flex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLXMf.png)